# Performance Testing for a Micro service

Tags: performance-testing

I am new to performance testing and we are planning to go live to production soon. Our service is written in kotlin and we are using spring boot. I am confused about whether to benchmark Individual APIs or benchmark scenarios where we have multiple APIs like Create, Get, Perform and Finalise (Assume these 4 steps complete one operation).

Comment: This question is a little bit ambiguous. Do you have an idea of how much traffic you'll be seeing? Benchmarking accurately is extremely hard to do in a Micro-Service environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load pattern needs to be realistic otherwise your test won't make a lot of sense.

So the network footprint your load testing tool generates must match the anticipated production one generated either by real users or by upstream systems.

If a real user goes through all these steps as one [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing) - you should design your test to hit all the endpoints sequentially on each iteration of each virtual user. This way you will be able to catch any possible [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) connected with the concurrency. Also design your [workload model](https://www.perfmatrix.com/performance-test-workload-modelling/) to mimic the anticipated real production traffic, i.e. if the endpoints are being invoked by real users using real browsers or mobile devices add realistic [think times](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9) between operations

Also it might be a good idea to test the whole integrated system as it acts at the speed of the slowest component.

More information: [Performance Testing Microservices with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-microservices)